# Limiting gate voltage for BUZ11 MOSFET in PWM with 24V power supply

Tags: mosfet, pwm, voltage-divider, zener

I'm newbie in electronics looking for an advice on how to properly limit gate voltage for BUZ11 MOSFET in my PWM regulator for a DC motor.
Currently I'm using it with 12V power supply and it works OK, but I want to use it with 25,2V (LiPo 6S), so the gate voltage should be limited to < 20V.
Thinking about Zener diode 1N4745A (16V).
Will it work for schematic below?

**Schematic (for 12V power supply):**
[image]

**Zener diode:**

[image]

**UPD**
I'll also use 78L12 LDO to power NE555.

Comment: It might, but that won't be the only problem - the NE555 can only hande 18V so it would also fry if connected to 25V.

Comment: Oh, I've forgot to mention that I'll use 78L12 LDO to power NE555.

Comment: If you would use 12V linear voltage regulator for powering the NE555 why would you think you'll need to "protect" a MOSFET?

Comment: @NStorm, so if I'm using LDO to power NE555, then I'm also limiting it's output to MOSFET. Actually, I haven't thought about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The zener will be useless as you seem to be powering the NE555 with 12V, so you don't need any protection for FET gate.